# How to override laravel auto redirection if session exists

Tags: laravel-5.7

Hello i am new in laravel and i am working on laravel 5.7 i have 2 different auth tables one is users and other is companies first is how can i check that from which table is user logged in and second when i close and open browser laravel auto redirects to home if session exist but i also want to add check their to redirect user on certain page means if user logged in from user table redirect to abc view and if company is logged in from company table redirects to xyz view how can i override ?

Comment: Looks like you're looking for multiple authentication is that right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what i do for multiple auth tables :

1. Go to config > auth.php

Add Guard

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'company' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'companies',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

Add Provider

```
'providers' => [
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

     'companies' => [
         'driver' => 'eloquent',
         'model' => App\Companies::class,
     ],
],
```

Add Password

```
   'passwords' => [
        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'companies' => [
            'provider' => 'companies',
            'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
```

2. GO to App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated

Update handel method

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if ($guard === 'admin' && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/admin');
        }
        if ($guard === 'company' && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/company');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Now i'm asumming you've different controller for users and companies in that case you can add middleware in you're controller

```
public function __construct()
    {
        // For Admin Users
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');

        // For Companies Users
        //$this->middleware('auth:company');
    }
```

Or you can add middleware in the route as well

Example

```
Route::group([
    'namespace'    => 'Companies',
    'middleware'   => 'auth:company'
], function () {
    // Authentication Routes...
    Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
});
```

I Hope this helps.